# qemu manager - virtual machine: "QEMU console not connected"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

Hello I have installed qemu manager virtualization program on my gateway amd e2-3800 windows 10 laptop, in order to install ubuntbu 16.04.

i have created a virtual machine, using the default definitions (beside giving the maximum ram of 2gb).

i have downloaded the ubunbu 16.04 imag file, pinted the "CD-ROM" drive of the virtual machine to the image fileand and run the virtual machine.

It didn't worked as expectd - the console and the monitor are empty and at the botom of the windows is written "QEMU console not connected",

there is nothing in "google" for this problem, and i have watched several youtube videos on using QEMU to see wether i have made some error in dfining the virtual machine, i have also read the manual... but came up with, well... nothing.

Does anybody have any idia or recomendations?

thank you in adanced.

chen.

Comment: Do you have the full command-line used?

Comment: Hello stian, I am not using the command line while building the virtual machine since the Qemu manager works on Windows 10, and not on linux. all the command-line recomendation I saw in various instructions were designed for linux. Is that what you ment? or are you asking about command line within the virtual machine it self? or somthing else?

Comment: I have not used to qemu manager myself. The few times I have used qemu, I have launched it manually from command-line. Is it possible to see what arguments the manager tries to start qemu with?

Comment: And, have you chosen a video card?

Comment: Hey stain, firts thank you for your helping efforts. it is very nice of you. well... i didn't know i need to do so actually. I have Tried the different options, after you asked me but yet... no result. What may be the main problem if the console is not connected? Is it about the "Hardware" of the virtual machine? of is it about the advanced definitions? or the problem my be in a completely another place? where  is it recommended to search? and how? about the argeumnts of qemu? where can i see them? and - have you used the qemu manger with the command line of windows? with the same instruction?

Comment: As far as i can see, qemu manager (windows) is not maintained anymore. If you do not need qemu specifically, virtualbox is free, and very easy to use

Comment: I think you are right Stian, and i eventually I actually decided to give up and used Oracle Virtualbox instead... shame on me for giving up :)... but... some time you just need to move forwared... Any way I have installed Lubuntu on my virtaul Machine whice suppose to be faster then regular ubuntu since it is aimed for computers with low hardware capabilities. it can be found under ubuntu flavoures - here: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours or here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-flavours

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after decreasing the VM's RAM to 1 GB it worked okay.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I have been using VirtualBox for quit some time and i thik i would love to keep on doing do - but i do hava a laptop in which the VirtualBox Does not work so well, maybe I will try it ther and i would report on the result when i will do. thank you any way for you answer

Answer (score 0):

Hardware -> Video Card, select other options.
In my case, running OVMF, I select "None", then it works.

[image: Video Card set]